# Mayavi when interaction is not updating plot

Tags: python, mayavi

In `update_plot` function I added print statement to check if I am getting correct data after interacting with scene, I can see I am getting correct value but plot itself is not updated. I am not where I am doing wrong. I think I am doing something wrong when I pass data back to `scaler_field`

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Instance, \
                    on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item, HGroup
from tvtk.pyface.scene_editor import SceneEditor
from mayavi.tools.mlab_scene_model import \
                    MlabSceneModel
from mayavi.core.ui.mayavi_scene import MayaviScene
from mayavi import mlab

class Visualization(HasTraits):
    mySlice = Range(0, 400, 100) # slice number
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    def __init__(self):
        HasTraits.__init__(self)
        data = InlinemySlice(self.mySlice) # call new data
        self.x_source = self.scene.mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data)
        self.plot = self.scene.mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(self.x_source, plane_orientation='x_axes',  colormap='Greys', vmin=-0.020505040884017944 ,vmax=0.020505040884017944)

    @on_trait_change('mySlice')
    def update_plot(self):
        x = InlinemySlice(self.mySlice)
        print(x)
        y_source = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x)
        self.plot.mlab_source.trait_set(y_source)

    # the layout of the dialog created
    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                    height=500, width=600, show_label=False),
                HGroup( 'mySlice' ),
                )

visualization = Visualization()
visualization.configure_traits()
```

Comment: It seems you're missing the key argument to `trait_set()`, see the [interactive example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mlab_interactive_dialog.html#example-mlab-interactive-dialog) for a documented functional example

Comment: if I do `self.plot.mlab_source.trait_set(x=y_source)` I am getting error `traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'x' trait of a MArraySource instance must be an array, but a value of <mayavi.sources.array_source.ArraySource `

Comment: What about `scalars=y_source`? I would assume x, y and z modify the location of the data which is plotted, whereas scalars modifies the actual values.